# state invariant use in sequence diagram

Tags: java, uml, sequence-diagram

I am trying to create a sequence diagram for a module that makes use of settings to make it customizable for various users. I want to depict this in the diagram. Should I use the state Invariant ? if not what would be the most suitable way to depict this

Comment: When you say "customizable for various users" do you mean the diagram (what it shows) or the module? I guess the latter. So you want to know how to show the settings affect the module?

Comment: @ThomasKilian The sequence should capture the different modules each user [Distribution groups] would be directed to based on external configurable settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each diagram is showing some specific context of a model. In this case I would split the whole sequence into a couple of different SDs. Starting with the main SD you can show how the settings are evaluated and lead to according diagram gates. You can make use of a fragments to distinguish between the single user cases:

[image]

Then for the single cases create individual SDs showing the specialized flows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Thomas This helps.